# How to get the data from jsonb using hql query

Tags: json, postgresql, hibernate, hql, jsonb

I have in my database a column that called "info" from a type of jsonb that looks like this:

```
info={'duration','metrics'}
```

I want to use a hql query to get the data of 'duration'

this is the query I'm trying to do:

```
    @Query(value = "select new com.hyginex.service.statistic.dto.NewWristbandRecordByUser(wrp.user.id, wrp.recordTimestamp, wrp.id, wrp.device.id, wrp.rssi, wrp.beacon.id, wrp.beacon.locatableType) " +
        "from WristbandRecordProcessed wrp where wrp.user.id = :userId and wrp.rssi is null and wrp.recordTimestamp > :lastTimestamp and wrp.recordType = 'HANDWASH' and (wrp.info->'duration')*(wrp.avgCrossing)>100 order by wrp.recordTimestamp ")
```

but I'm getting error when i do:

```
 (wrp.info->'duration')
```

i tried even without the ' ' and still didn't work.

Comment: HQL is an abstraction (obfuscation) layer on top of SQL. It does not know of any advanced features of the underlying DBMS. You can't do that with HQL, you will need a native query to exploit the full power of SQL.